# How to pass request attribute to HTML:checkbox

Tags: html, jstl, struts-1

Hi
 I am creating checkboxes dynamically, so just wanted to know how to pass request attribute to `<html:checkbox />` tag.

Eg: request.setAttribute("counter_1", false);

how to set it in below code snippet.

```
<html:checkbox property=? />
```

Comment: The JSTL doesn't have an html:checkbox tag. I guess you're talking about struts1 tags. Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

`<html:checkbox />` is struts 1.x tag and to get the value from request attribute using jstl you can use below code snippet

```
<html:checkbox property="${counter_1}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create `ActionForm` with your properties like

```
public class YourForm extends ActionForm {
private boolean counter;
// getters, setters
}
```

Then declare your form in the struts config. And after that:

```
<html:checkbox property="counter" />
```